# PHP regex - valid float number

Tags: php, regex

I want user only input 0-9 and only once "."

```
 patt = /[^0-9(.{1})]/

 1.2222 -> true
 1.2.2  -> false (only once '.')
```

help me , thank !

Answer (score 26):

```
/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$/
```

This matches normal floats e.g. `3.14`, shorthands for decimal part only e.g. `.5` and integers e.g. `9` as well as negative numbers.

Comment: You need to enclose the alternation in parentheses, or else the start-of-string anchor will only be enforced with integers, and the end-of-string anchor only with decimals.

Answer (score 24):

this is what you're looking for

```
$re = "~        #delimiter
    ^           # start of input
    -?          # minus, optional
    [0-9]+      # at least one digit
    (           # begin group
        \.      # a dot
        [0-9]+  # at least one digit
    )           # end of group
    ?           # group is optional
    $           # end of input
~xD";
```

this only accepts "123" or "123.456", not ".123" or "14e+15". If you need these forms as well, try is_numeric

Comment: @AntonioCS it is for $ ending delimiter
[ref about PCRE modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
`D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)
If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is ignored if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.`
FYI: the x is for Extended: for suppressing any whitespace chars

Answer (score 9):

Regular Expressions are for matching string patterns. If you are not explicitly after validating the input string's format (but the actual value), you can also use

```
filter_var("1.33", FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
```

to make sure the input can be used as a float value. This will return `FALSE` if it is not a float and the float or integer value otherwise. Any [type juggling](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) rules apply.

Comment: This does not fit the OPs requirements/description: e.g. it allows `123e-4`

Comment: @salathe yes, like I said: use it when you are after the *value*. Dont use it if you are after validating the *string format*. `123e-4` is still a float (`0.123`).

Answer (score 7):

This regex:

```
\d*(?:\.\d+)?
```

will give results:

```
123 -> true
123.345 -> true
123. -> true
.345 -> true
0.3345 -> true
```

However, you must check emptiness of the input before using it because the regex also permit *zero-length* input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/is_numeric) with the caveat that it accepts a bit more than one usually wants (e.g. `1e4`).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following regex that seems to work best for my test inputs so far,

`/^-?(\d|[1-9]+\d*|\.\d+|0\.\d+|[1-9]+\d*\.\d+)$/`

It matches integer using the first two alternatives

`\d|[1-9]+\d*`

Then it look for numbers like .5, .55, .05 etc., that is beginning with a .

`\.\d+`

Then it looks for the same as previous but a 0 before the .

`0\.\d+`

Then finally it looks for patterns integer and decimal parts, such as 5.5, 5.05 etc.

`[1-9]+\d*\.\d+`

You can test the regex in this link

[Validate float - regex101](https://regex101.com/library/6qoUGI)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php ? But anyhow, the RegEx would be `^[\d]+(|\.[\d]+)$` have fun!

Comment: None of those character classes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-numeric.php) if you're not experienced with regular expressions.

As to your regex: `.` matches all characters, `\.` matches a dot. `{1}` is not necessary. And I have no clue what you're trying to do with `[^ ... ]`. Read the [regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you really want to use regular expressions somewhere in your code.