# Regular expression for float in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP regex - valid float number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941052/php-regex-valid-float-number)

what will be regular expression in php as well as for javascript  for float numbers?

I waht to match values like 3, 3.3 or 0.3 and 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no token for float numbers. If you want to match a float you have to use digit + point + digit, something like this:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Comment: `1.2.3.4.5` will match it. You've confused `*` quantifier with `?`

Comment: @zerkms Oh right.. I'll edit, thanks!

Comment: `\d+(\.\d+)?` matches `3`, `3.3`, `0.3` & not `1.2.3.4.5`

Comment: @KevinD. because I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
is_numeric($nb);
```

JS:

```
!isNaN(+nb);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a given string is an int/float:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+){0,1}$/
```

If you want to match *all* numbers that in a given string:

```
/\b\d+(\.\d+){0,1}\b/g
```

That should give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

Float's can also be written as `.3`, this would be equal to `0.3` in that case to cover all you'd need:

```
/((?:\d)?(?:.\d+)?)/
```

This will group the result as one whole string, without splitting it into subresults.

So this would match `33`, `3.3` & `.33`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want :
Only check? do as Florian Margaine said : `is_numeric($nb)` in PHP for float numbers and `ctype_digits($nb)` for integers. in JS `!isNaN(+nb);` for float and `typeof($nb) == "Integer"` for integers.

If you want to convert your numbers (and check in the same time) :

```
//for floats
$floatNb = (float) $nb;
if($floatNb != 0 || $nb === "0")//now you are sure that $nb was a float and $floatNb is the float representation
```

If you got international numbers, use the [number formatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) from intl extension :

```
<?php
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = "1.234.567,891";
echo numfmt_parse($fmt, $num)."\n";
```

Regex are NEVER good for type checking