# a .htaccess RewriteRule that takes to Double arguments and sends it to a webservice in php

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` file so that it accepts two double arguments (a latitude and a longitude) and redirects to a php webservice controller with those arguments as `GET` variables.

So far and with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941052/php-regex-valid-float-number), I got this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api/geopointsnearlocation/(/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$)/(/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$)/$   api/GeoPointsRestController.php?lat=$1&lng=$2 [nc,qsa]
```

but when I use this url:

```
http://localhost/api/geopointsnearlocation/29%2E9876/50%2E8765/
```

to call my webservice I get this error message:

> The requested URL /api/geopointsnearlocation/1.2/2.3/ was not found
>   on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

I tried to pass the numbers as `29.9876` or `29`, but none of them work.I am guessing somehow my regular expression is wrong.

could anybody help me?

PS: I am pretty sure that `GeoPointsRestController.php` exists and is in the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regex as `^` and `$` are not matched in the middle:

```
RewriteRule ^api/geopointsnearlocation/(-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+))/(-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+))/?$ api/GeoPointsRestController.php?lat=$1&lng=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```